# Data/Partition recovery Help Needed

Tags: data-recovery

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 over my windows 7. While installing Ubuntu, I have made some mistake and my all partitions are gone. Previously there were 5 partitions (NTFS) of 200 GB on windows 7. But now I can see only 1 partion (ext4) of 1 TB in ubuntu system.

Unfortunately, I can't access my data now. Anybody can help me in this please? Can I recover my data / partitions?

I have only installed ubuntu 13.04, I haven't installed any other software on my ubuntu.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you mistakenly deleted a partition, and want to get your data and the partition back, then you can use Testdisk.

> TestDisk is powerful free data recovery software! It was primarily
>   designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks
>   bootable again when these symptoms are caused by faulty software,
>   certain types of viruses or human error (such as accidentally deleting
>   a Partition Table). Partition table recovery using TestDisk is really
>   easy.<sup>1</sup>

To install TestDisk, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

For step by step instructions on how to use see [TestDisk Step By Step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for help bro. I will try Testdisk. Actually, I haven't deleted NTFS partition, but it was overwritten by ext4 partition while installing Ubuntu. Hope this help me.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly straight forward; here is a link to a Wiki on the tool which will help out a lot: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk The wiki has a lot of guides and picture tutorials on how to use it and how to properly and safely recover the lost files.