# HDD recovery tool

Tags: software-recommendation, data-recovery

I accidentally unplugged one of my HDD's from power while running. When I boot now, the name of the drive is display as: `zzzzzz` and some other funny characters. Which is the best recovery tool for that on Linux/Ubuntu?

The HDD is NTFS formatted and has about 500GB.

Greetings, p.

Comment: Take a look at my [Answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/292375/data-partition-recovery-help-needed/292396#292396), and see if it helps.

Comment: I'm sure you searched before you posted this so can you tell us what you've already tried that didn't work from [our many existing questions on recovering data from ntfs](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery+ntfs)?

Comment: You can follow instructions in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Answer (score 1):

Try testdisk.

To install, open a terminal and enter

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

The recovery starts with

```
sudo testdisk
```

There will be a menu driven routine to recover partitions.

First select create to start a recovery:
[image: Menu after start]

Then select your disk:

[image: disk selection]

and the partition table type (I have intel):

[image: partition table type seletor]

The last step is to hit Analyse:

[image]