# Access USB Flash drive from Wine

Tags: wine, permissions, filesystem, usb-drive

Im trying to use recuva (a file recovery program) on WINE because some files on a corrupt USB Flash drive just did not get restored using PhotoRec for linux.

The problem is, I can't select the USB Flash Drive (/media/) folder and thus I can't scan.

I don't have access to a windows computer immediately and I must try all possible things to recover the files.

How do I permit recuva/WINE to access my Flash Drive?

Comment: Have you tried using ~testdisk`? http://askubuntu.com/questions/298131/hdd-recovery-tool/298152#298152

Comment: Yes it comes with PhotoRec. I've tried testdisk and PhotoRec.

Comment: And you expect the other programm to be more successfull? This is a low level access... I think you need a real or virtal machine with windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wine does not support usb drives without patches, and even with patches support is limited.

See: http://wiki.winehq.org/USB

I agree with the advice Manuel gave you, if you want to use a Windows application, run it from windows.

In my experience, if photorec does not work, you may wish to consider professional data recovery.

If you want to continue to do the work yourself, you can start here:

http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/03/digital-forensic-analysis-using-backtrack-part-1/

http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/04/digital-forensic-analysis-using-backtrack-part-2/

Comment: Thanks. I've made a backup of the drive for safety and will try using it on Windows.